# Formating smalldate data type from SQL Server in C# MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Is there an option to format `smalldate` from SQL Server 2012 in ASP.NET MVC and C#?

My intention is format date from `2014-03-21 19:00:00` to `21-03-2014 19:00` and display this format on page. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In sql server you could do something like

```
SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm') AS [DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm]

RESULT: 03-08-2014 22:26
```